# how to use windows media player to play listbox items in visual studio 2012 vb

Tags: vb.net, mp3, wav, wmp, listboxitems

I have 1,189 listboxitems a user can select from.  I want an audio file to play for each listboxitem that they click.  I know I can do:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources."filename here", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

and:

```
Dim sPath As String
    Dim mySound As Media.SoundPlayer
    sPath = "C:\wav\Genesis01.wav"
    mySound = New Media.SoundPlayer(sPath)
    mySound.Play()
```

for each listboxitem but I want to use hidden windows media player with only the controls play pause stop and volume available at each listboxitem they choose to click.

Is there a way to write a single piece of code that will allow the player controls to pop up on whichever item they click or does there need to be windows media player code for all 1,189 listboxitems individually?

The reason there are 1,189 listboxitems to choose from is because each listboxitem represents a chapter of the bible.  Genesis has 50 chapters - so there are 50 mp3 or wav files just for Genesis - Psalms has 150 chapters - so there are 150 mp3 or wav files for Psalms.  I was just wondering about cutting down some of the coding work with just a few lines of code if possible?  Thanks for your response.

I should clarify that I have a button for each book of the bible - so there are 39 old testament and 27 new testament buttons and each button contains a listbox with the particular chapters for that book.  Here is my code and here is what I have started to do:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If ListBox1.Visible = True Then
ListBox1.Visible = False
Else : ListBox1.Visible = True
```

and to play the file I started doing this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis01, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 1
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis02, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 2
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis03, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 3
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis04, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 4
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis05, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 5
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis06, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Case 6
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Genesis07, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Select
Private Sub Button42_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button42.Click
My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
ListBox1.ClearSelected()
End Sub
```

So I hope you can help me with a wmp with just the controls - play pause stop.  Just one player that will work for each listbox item.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it anyhow, which Im sure everyone knows:  Hopefully it can be improved with the wmp plugin.

```
Case 0
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis01.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 1
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis02.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 2
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis03.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 3
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis04.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 4
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis05.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 5
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis06.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
Case 6
      My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Bible\Genesis\Genesis07.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it on how to use windows media player to play my `listbox.selectedindex` files:

```
 Private Sub ListBox10_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox10.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ListBox10.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (1).wav"
        Case 1
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (2).wav"
        Case 2
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (3).wav"
        Case 3
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (4).wav"
        Case 4
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (5).wav"
        Case 5
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (6).wav"
        Case 6
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (7).wav"
        Case 7
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (8).wav"
        Case 8
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (9).wav"
        Case 9
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (10).wav"
        Case 10
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (11).wav"
        Case 11
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (12).wav"
        Case 12
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (13).wav"
        Case 13
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (14).wav"
        Case 14
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (15).wav"
        Case 15
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (16).wav"
        Case 16
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (17).wav"
        Case 17
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (18).wav"
        Case 18
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (19).wav"
        Case 19
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (20).wav"
        Case 20
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (21).wav"
        Case 21
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (22).wav"
        Case 22
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (23).wav"
        Case 23
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Bible\2Samuel\2Samuel (24).wav"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Button44_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button44.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub

Private Sub Button45_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button45.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause()
End Sub

Private Sub Button46_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button46.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop()
End Sub
```

Clicking the chapter name will play the audio - I have a pause and stop button that work and if I want to continue playing the audio from being paused - the play button works to continue playing.